# stack overflow error creating markers

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-maps-api-3, flex3, stack-overflow

I am using google maps javascript api V3 to create maps in our adobe flex based application. I am using flex iframes to communicate between flex and javascript api. I am having two issues.

I call a function in html file to create the map in div tag in html. Then map shows up but when I call another function to create the marker, I get stack overflow error. On analyzing this issue I found that somehow it is unable to get the reference of map which was created previous method. Is there a way to resolve this. Please find the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Google Maps Markers</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 650px; height: 250px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">


var map;

var DFWCenter =  new google.maps.LatLng(32.9017,-97.0405770);    

function showMap()
  {

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 15,
    center: DFWCenter,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID  
    });

 }  

function createCustomMarker(station,lat1, lang1){
    var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
      position:  new google.maps.LatLng(lat1,lang1),
      map: map
     });

  marker.setMap(map);
 }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not here.  Stack overflow is only going to occur if you recursively call a function, and it's not in this code.  Is there more?

Comment: I had the same error some time ago. The problem was in my case: lat1 or/and lang1 was not a float value. Do you typecheck?

Comment: I do not want to call createCustomMarker () from showMap() Method. The whole flow is 

1) Flex loads the page.
2) flex makes a call to load iFrame

<flexiframe:IFrame id="iFrameBySource"
   source="GmapDFW.html"  />

3) we call showMap() function in html file to display the map. showMap() function is above in the html file

4) when user click on show markers in Flex UI , we call showCustomMarkers() function to showthe markers on the map drawn 
 iFrameBySource.callIFrameFunction('createCustomMarker',[bagDeliveryTugCurrentLatitude,bagDeliveryTugCurrentLongitude]);

Comment: After this I get the stack overflow error.

Comment: Please don't mind, but have you tried it on any other browser too?

Comment: Yes..I have and I get the same error in chrome also. It does not display the error but it just doesn't render the map in dev tab. i show just a grey map

Answer (score 0):

@deejay: If you r not getting the reference of map, u can try this by taking it as a global variable, I tried this and was not able to produce your case as it was working simply fine, when I first call showMap() and then createCustomMarker().
Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aehp4406).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Google Maps Markers</title>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var DFWCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(32.9017, -97.0405770);

        function showMap() {

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                zoom: 15,
                center: DFWCenter,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            });
            createCustomMarker(DFWCenter.A, DFWCenter.F);
        }

        function createCustomMarker(lat1, lang1) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lang1),
                map: map
            });

            marker.setMap(map);
        }
        </script>
</head>

<body onload="showMap()">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 650px; height: 250px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I do not want to call createCustomMarker () from showMap() Method. The whole flow is 

1) Flex loads the page.
2) flex makes a call to load iFrame

<flexiframe:IFrame id="iFrameBySource"
   source="GmapDFW.html"  />

3) we call showMap() function in html file to display the map. showMap() function is above in the html file

4) when user click on show markers in Flex UI , we call showCustomMarkers() function to showthe markers on the map drawn 
 iFrameBySource.callIFrameFunction('createCustomMarker',[bagDeliveryTugCurrentLatitude,bagDeliveryTugCurrentLongitude]);

Comment: set map as global and I think that can help u. I think the problem is u call it before it is rendered into DOM, but I am not getting this error. Can u tell me, which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using IE 8. I set the map as gloabal also. I think the problem is shifting control between html and flex actionscript code. when I call the function in html to create marker, tit cant find the map object which was created earlier.